# Can't login to SQL Server due to active trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm playing around with triggers on our SQL Server. After dropping some logon triggers to allow login of some users from specific IP's only. Didn't get it to work.

Actually I do some auditing with a logon trigger.

When I try to login from grafana (was one of the users mentioned above) I get the message that it can't logon due to active triggers.

Here is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [LogonAuditTrigger] /* Creates trigger for logons */
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR LOGON
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @LogonTriggerData xml,
@EventTime datetime,
@LoginName varchar(50),
@ClientHost varchar(50),
@LoginType varchar(50),
@HostName varchar(50),
@AppName varchar(500)

SET @LogonTriggerData = eventdata()

SET @EventTime = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]', 'datetime')
SET @LoginName = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
SET @ClientHost = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
SET @HostName = HOST_NAME()
SET @AppName = APP_NAME()

INSERT INTO [LogonAudit].[dbo].[LogonAuditing]
(
SessionId,
LogonTime,
HostName,
ProgramName,
LoginName,
ClientHost
)
SELECT
@@spid,
@EventTime,
@HostName,
@AppName,
@LoginName,
@ClientHost

END
```

This is the error message:

> Error logging in with the username 'grafana' due to trigger execution

Disabling the trigger let Grafana login to the SQL Server, but I expect to get it work with activated trigger to log the logins.

Comment: Can you add TRY/CATCH handling to the trigger, and log the full error instead? What are the data types / null definitions of the logging table? Any chance any of your variables are NULL when they can't be, or exceed the size of those columns?

Comment: Also I feel like you can avoid the EventData XML altogether (this can be a pretty heavy payload) - you know what time it is (`getutcdate()`), you can get login name (e.g. `SUSER_SNAME()`, `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()`, etc.), and when is `ClientHost` ever going to be different from `HOST_NAME()`?

Comment: Well, this is my first try with triggers. ;-)
I have a windows authentication user in the server. With this user I can still login and the logins were logged by the trigger.
Only sql native users get blocked.

Comment: The other issue is even if your table's data types match the variable declarations, they don't seem big enough and they aren't the right type. Host name, program name, and login name can all be up to `nvarchar(128)` - and yes, they can support Unicode.

Comment: It's possible `LoginName` from the XML is NULL in the case of SQL auth logins, which would cause an underlying error if the column in the logging table doesn't allow NULL. Can you change that column to allow NULL temporarily? Also you never use `@LoginType`.

Comment: Does the `LOGIN` have a mapped `USER` in the database `LogonAudit` that can `INSERT` into the object `[dbo].[LogonAuditing]`?

Comment: @ Aaron: All columns allow NULLs
@ Thom: Yes, there is a grafana user in the LogonAudit database

Comment: But is the grafana user granted permission to insert to the `LogonAuditing` table?

Comment: I suggest you rethink this completely. You can use the much lighter XEvents system to log essential logon information. A logon trigger (especially the one you have) is very heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you can start by changing `LoginName` in the audit table to allow `NULL`, since this may not be available the way you're pulling from the XML in the case of SQL authentication logins. (And in fact I don't think you necessarily need the heavy `EventData()` XML at all.)

Next, you need to make sure your audit table supports the data that you might try to insert - login names, program names, and host names can all be up to `nvarchar(128)`, so that's how your columns and variable declarations should be declared.

Though, I don't think it needs both `ClientHost` and `HostName` since I don't know when those could be different.

Then hopefully you can log any error messages somewhere else.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [LogonAuditTrigger]
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @EventTime  datetime      = getutcdate(),
          @LoginName  nvarchar(128) = ORIGINAL_LOGIN(),
          @HostName   nvarchar(128) = HOST_NAME(),
          @AppName    nvarchar(128) = APP_NAME();

  BEGIN TRY
    INSERT LogonAudit.dbo.LogonAuditing
    (
      SessionId,
      LogonTime,
      HostName,
      ProgramName,
      LoginName
    )
    SELECT
      @@spid,
      @EventTime,
      @HostName,
      @AppName,
      @LoginName;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    INSERT dbo.LoggingTable ... stuff including ERROR_MESSAGE() ...
    THROW();
  END CATCH
END
```

The only other problem would be if the `grafana` user doesn't have the ability to write to the audit table (or the logging table). Try to insert a row manually using `EXECUTE AS`.

Comment: My first try was you last thought. I put grafana to the db_datawriter role and guess what, grafana can login now and the logins get logged.

Comment: @Martin you could just  GRANT INSERT ON dbo.LogonAuditing TO PUBLIC; rather than adding them to the db_datawriter role